# Strtok and ability to ignore usernames?

Tags: c++, strtok

So I'm currently doing a project where we need to parse sentences (more specifically tweets) by word and store the frequencies of words and the words themselves in a vector pair (with a custom find function to increment frequencies).

Im currently using strtok to parse the sentences and i was wondering if you could ingore any words that have a symbol `@` at the beginning of them. I currently have my delimiter for the strtok function as a bunch of non useful symbols and spaces `!@#&()–[{}]:;',?/*\".+\\^` and it ignores them correctly, but say I have a word: `@thisismyusername`, is there a way to ignore the whole word, including the `'thisismyusername'` and not just the `@`?

I've been looking for documentation on something like this but haven't found anything yet.

Here is my strtok parsing code:

```
char* tempMap;
tempMap = strtok (tempHolderPos," !@#&()–[{}]:;',?/*\".+\\^");
```

*`tempHolderPos` is the full sentence.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I would think it easier to split on spaces and any first character of the split that is not alpha, don't stash it.

Comment: `strtok` is a very primitive function, for more complicated parsing, look at `regex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly that. For instance, something like the following will work with your `strtok` loop:

```
someloop {
    ptr = strtok (NULL, yourdelims); 
    if (*ptr == '@')
        continue;` 
    ...
}
```

After getting a token from `strtok` you simply check if the first character is a `'@'` and if so, go get the next word at this point -- effectively ignoring the word beginning with `'@'`.

Recall, when you dereference a character pointer, you get the character itself. When called on a `char *` variable name (the beginning address for the pointer), you get the 1st character. So you just dereference your pointer to your token and check if the first char is `'@'` and if so, go get the next word, skipping all additional processing that would be done on the token.

Comment: Awesome, I had to add the `ptr = strtok (NULL, yourdelims);` to get it to move to the next word but now it works great. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, yes sorry, that presumes a previous call to `ptr = strtok (yourstring, yourdelms);` before entering the loop. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) reference, I think you can't do that *directly*. It would be easy though to ignore any token that starts with `@` and just continue without saving it.